# Why can't this autoencoder reach zero loss?

Tags: keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I'm building an autoencoder and was wondering why the loss didn't converge to zero after 500 iterations. So I created this "illustrative" autoencoder with encoding dimension equals to the input dimension. 
To make sure that there was nothing wrong with the data, I created a random array sample of shape (30000, 100) and fed it as input and output (x = y). The NN is just supposed to learn to keep the inputs as they are. So why doesn't it reach zero loss?

```
# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 100

inputs = Input(shape=x_rand.shape[1:])

encoded = Dense(100, activation='relu')(inputs)
encoded = Dense(100, activation='relu')(encoded)

encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(100, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(100, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(x_rand.shape[-1], activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
history = autoencoder.fit(x_rand, x_rand, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Is the input between 0 and 1?

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes, generated with numpy.random.rand()

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using sigmoid as last activation function?